# How to return the response of ajax to called function? It always returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url:"<?php echo TESTMINE_APP_URL; ?>/ajax/export-details",
    data:'paginationHash='+paginationHash+'&exportType='+exportType+'&userId='+userId,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(requestId){
        var popup = window.open("sample1.php","exportWindow");
        popup.document.write('<html><body>Status: <span id="status">Please wait...</span></body></html>');
        setInterval(function(){
            var status = checkStatusOfRequest(requestId);
            alert(status);
            popup.document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = status;
        }, 9000)
    }
});
```

Comment: I am returning status from checkStatusOfRequest function.. it displaying undefined

Comment: `console.log(requestId)` inside the success function to see what is being fetched by the ajax call

Comment: console log the `requestId` you are getting in ajax success, and paste it here or I think you can access it like this -   `success:function(response){ alert(response.requestId); }`

Comment: I want  checkStatusOfRequest function result.

Comment: function checkStatusOfRequest(requestId)
 {
  $.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  url:"<?php echo TESTMINE_APP_URL; ?>/ajax/check-export-status",
  data:'requestId='+requestId,
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(status) 
  {
   var exportStatus=status;
   
    return exportStatus;
  }
  });

  
  
 }

Comment: we can get that if we come to know the result coming in the response first ?